# register / FlipFLop implementatino in Python

Tags: python, state-machine, persistent

I need to make a Python simulation of a HW-design. The design has registers in it (i.e. some data is stored from clock to clock).

In MATLAB I would just declare persistent variables that would store data between function calls (non-persistent variables are flushed).

After some searching and browsing I found options of using generators and classes, but both seem a bit cumbersome.

My question is:

Is there a simple way to declare some variables inside a function in a way, that will have them store the data between calls to that function? Something like the following pseudocode:

```
myfunc(some inputs)
    declare persistent aa,bb,cc 
    if running_first_time:
        aa,bb,cc = 0
        xx,yy = 0

    else:
        <do some logical and algebraic stuff with inputs and 
        aa,bb,cc store some results in aa,bb,cc until the 
        next function call, calculate xx and yy outputs>
    return xx,yy
```

Comment: What you're describing is exactly what generators are used for. They're functions with state.

Comment: Does the function get inputs also on subsequent calls?

Comment: Have you seen the `global` keyword in python?

Comment: @L3viathan Yep, Every function call new set of inputs is received (like in filter for example, where each "clock" the filter gets new inputs but they outputs are calculated using historical values as well)

Comment: @Balaji Ambresh I did but I will have multiple instances of the same unit, so I can't use global - the memory would be shared across the instances and I need it local to each unit.

Comment: Consider using a `class` or go with `nonlocal` as suggested by @Serge Ballesta

Answer (score 1):

The Pythonic way is a *closure*. In Python you define an outer function that initialize persistent variables, defines an inner function and returns it. The inner function can then use the persistent variables:

```
def builder():
    tot = 0
    def foo(x):
        nonlocal tot
        tot += x
        return tot
    return foo
```

Usage:

```
>>> foo = builder()
>>> foo(1)
1
>>> foo(2)
3
>>> foo(5)
8
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you could implement this using generators:

```
def myfunc(some, inputs):
    aa = bb = cc = xx = yy = 0
    while True:
        some, inputs = yield xx, yy
        # do some stuff with some, inputs, aa, bb, cc, xx, yy...
```

The way you would use this would be like this:

```
>>> func_instance = myfunc(first, inputs)
>>> first_xx, first_yy = next(func_instance)
>>> second_xx, second_yy = func_instance.send((second, inputs))
>>> # etc.
```

Generators, especially those using `.send`, take some time getting used to, but are very powerful.